# ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken When Submitting

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a program that allows users to enter their song for a certain event. You must enter in the partycode for that event in order for it to submit. Here is a screenshot of what it looks like: 
[image]

When I submit it gives me this error: 
[image]

Here is what my SongsController looks like:

```
class SongsController < ApplicationController

    def new
        @song = Song.new
    end

    def create
        current_event = Event.find(song_params[:event_id])
        @song = current_event.songs.build(song_params)
        if @song.save
            flash[:success] = "Success"
            redirect_to event_path(@song.event)
        else
            flash[:error] = "Failed"
        end

    end

    def destroy
    end
    private

      def song_params
        params.require(:song).permit(:event_id, :artist, :title, :genre)
      end
end
```

event model

```
class Event < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :partycode, presence: true, length: {minimum: 5}
  has_many :songs, dependent: :destroy  

end
```

song model

```
class Song < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :event
  validates :artist, presence: true
  validates :title,  presence: true
end
```

new.html.erb(song)

```
<br>
<br>
<h1> Member page </h1>
<div class ="container">
  <div class="jumbotron">
    <h2> Select an event to add songs to: </h2>
    <%= form_for Song.new do |f| %>
        <%= f.collection_select(:event_id, Event.all, :id, :name) %>
    <h3> Enter your song </h3>
    <%= form_for Song.new do |f| %>
      <%= f.text_field :artist, placeholder: "Artist" %>
      <%= f.text_field :title,  placeholder: "Title" %>
      <%= f.text_field :genre,  placeholder: "Genre" %>
    <h2> Enter the partycode for that event: </h2>
    <%= form_for Event.new do |f| %>
      <%= f.text_field :partycode %>
      <%= f.submit "Submit", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>
    <% end %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

What can I do to make this functionality of my website work? Any help is greatly appreciated thanks

Comment: Did you setup correct relationship between song and event?

Comment: I will post my relationships

Comment: Please add your view code as well .

Comment: the view code to which files? @dp7

Comment: @Aaron you are submitting a form, would like to see the form code present in your view

Comment: How about struct of tables. I think your `songs` must be have field `event_id`. If it is. You don't need `current_event = Event.find(song_params[:event_id])`, just use `@song = Song.new(song_params)

Comment: I edited my question now showing the forms

Comment: Amazing I got it thanks @DuyetNguyen

Comment: I think @dp7 has answer for you :D

Comment: I'm not sure about syntax. But take a look on my answer. Use only 1 form plz.

Comment: `partycode` is an attribute of which model `Event` or `Song` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see many form_for nesting on your views. It's impossible. Only one submit for a form.

I think you may want to change your `_form.html.erb`

```
<div class ="container">
  <div class="jumbotron">
    <h2> Select an event to add songs to: </h2>
    <%= form_for @song do |f| %>
      <%= f.collection_select(:event_id, Event.all, :id, :name) %>
      <h3> Enter your song </h3>
      <%= f.text_field :artist, placeholder: "Artist" %>
      <%= f.text_field :title,  placeholder: "Title" %>
      <%= f.text_field :genre,  placeholder: "Genre" %>
      <h2> Enter the partycode for that event: </h2>
      <%= f.text_field :partycode %>
      <%= f.submit "Submit", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have completely messed up your form. Ideally you should have one form but here you have just kept one form within another form using `form_for`.

I would recommend you to have a look at the [`form_for documentation`](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.3/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/form_for) .